# Concatenate memory blocks in C++

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, file-handling

I made 10 fragments of binary executable and kept them
in separate memory blocks. I used setter like this.

```
  void SetCDataStream(u_char* _cDataStream, size_t _sizeData)
    {
        cDataStream = new u_char [_sizeData]; 
        memmove(cDataStream,_cDataStream, _sizeData);
    }
```

And I'm getting these blocks using getter like this

```
u_char *GetCDataStream()
{
    return cDataStream;
}
```

And putting it into vector in proper order from beginning to end of file content

```
std::vector<u_char*> vecCDataStream;
```

I want to concatenate each entry of the vector to form original file and should be able to execute it.
is there better way to do this?

Comment: You need to remember the size of each block as well, as I bet each "memory block" can contain NUL bytes.

Comment: You should make the fragments already *vectors* of u_char (there is a vector constructor which takes two pointers and initializes the vector with the data between the pointers). Then it's not difficult to [concatenate them.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201718/3150802). `std::vector::data()` can be used to eventually get at the bytes in the large vector.  Whether you then are able to actually *execute* the code stored in the concatenated vector is a different matter. I remember that some guy demonstrated how to execute a function stored in a char array but it was not trivial.

Comment: Actually, [it doesn't look difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39867396/3150802) once one knows how to put the array in memory with execute permission, which needs some system magic.

Comment: @Botje I've the size of each block as well and it may contains null bytes too.

Comment: Oh, and if you use vector chunks already the GetCDataStream() can simply return vectors *by value* (if you are modern C++); modern C++ with move constructors makes that efficient. No need to struggle with raw pointers.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Actually I know how to do it using memcpy and  dump the bytes to file. but I was just wondering, if there is better way. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your question is unclear and lacks motivation. If you are coding some ELF linker, there are better ways. Look inside the C++ source code of the [GNU gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) linker

Comment: If you are generating code on the fly, consider also [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) perhaps with [dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you don't need manual memory management at all and you don't need to preserve the original memory blocks positions in memory. In that case, you could use `std::vector` to store the blocks - and squash them into one big block if you wish.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// A class to keep a number of blocks
class BlockMaster {
public:
    using block_t = std::vector<uint8_t>;

    explicit BlockMaster(size_t init_size = 0) : blocks{init_size} {}

    // Add a new block
    void AddDataStream(const uint8_t* begin, const uint8_t* end) {
        blocks.emplace_back(begin, end);
    }

    size_t size() const noexcept { return blocks.size(); }

    // random access to the stored blocks
    block_t& operator[](size_t block_number) noexcept {
        return blocks[block_number];
    }
    const block_t& operator[](size_t block_number) const noexcept {
        return blocks[block_number];
    }

    // support for iterating over the stored blocks
    auto cbegin() const noexcept { return blocks.cbegin(); }
    auto cend() const noexcept { return blocks.cend(); }
    auto begin() const noexcept { return cbegin(); }
    auto end() const noexcept { return cend(); }
    auto begin() noexcept { return blocks.begin(); }
    auto end() noexcept { return blocks.end(); }

    // create a BlockMaster with one huge block from the stored blocks
    BlockMaster GetSquashedBlocks() {
        BlockMaster result(1);
        for(const block_t& block : *this) {
            result[0].insert(result[0].end(), block.begin(), block.end());
        }
        return result;
    }

private:
    std::vector<block_t> blocks;
};

// stream all the stored blocks to a file (as if they were one big block, so
// you don't need to squash them for this)
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& ofs, const BlockMaster& bm) {
    for(const auto& block : bm)
        ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(block.data()),
                  static_cast<std::streamsize>(block.size()));
    return ofs;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char memory[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    BlockMaster bm;
    bm.AddDataStream(memory + 0, memory + 3);
    bm.AddDataStream(memory + 4, memory + 8);

    std::cout << bm.size() << "\n--\n";

    for(const auto& block : bm) {
        std::cout << ' ' << block.size() << '\n';
    }

    bm = bm.GetSquashedBlocks();

    std::cout << "--\n";

    std::cout << bm.size() << "\n--\n";
    for(const auto& block : bm) {
        std::cout << ' ' << block.size() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2    // blockmasters number of stored blocks
--
 3   // first blocks size
 4   // second blocks size
--
1    // blockmasters number of stored blocks after squashing
--
 7   // size of the one block after squashing
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each `Block` has a `GetSize()` member and a `GetCDataStream()` member, you can simply create an `std::ofstream` object and write each block using the `std::ofstream::write` method:

```
std::ofstream out("test.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
for (Block& b : blocks) {
    out.write(b.GetCDataStream(), b.GetSize());
}
out.close();
```

Note that it is up to you that the concatenation of all blocks is a valid executable for your platform (PE on Windows, ELF on Linux, Mach-O on macOS).

Comment: Thanks. Its ELF on Linux. But I wanted to first assemble all the chunks in single memory block and dump the bytes to file. you have any suggestion?